# Define KDL tree structure in C++

Tags: ros, kdl, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question is not completely related to ROS. However since KDL is used heavily inside ROS, I am requesting and posting here.

I have a URDF file, which I could parse and build KDL tree using [kdl_parser](http://wiki.ros.org/kdl_parser) using the following way:

```
KDL::Tree my_tree;
if (!kdl_parser::treeFromFile("robot.urdf", my_tree)){
    std::cout << "Failed to construct kdl tree"<< std::endl;
}
```

However, due to a project limitation, I can not use ROS and hence unable to use kdl_parser. Please note that I am working on Windows OS. Below is a snippet of KDL tree of my robot which contains only revolute joints:

[image: image description]

Please note that the above image is a part of the big tree, however, to keep this post shorter I cropped it and added leaf nodes.

*Since I am not able to parse the URDF file, I am thinking to construct the KDL tree manually. Although, it is not good practice and I am limited with resources here.*

**Can someone please explain me how to construct a KDL tree for the above image?** All the joints are revolute and I am only interested in performing forward Kinematics.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316333/define-kdl-tree-structure-in-c++/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2019-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See here http://orocos.org/wiki/main-page/kdl-wiki/user-manual/kinematic-trees/kinematic-trees-kdl-10x and here http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/orocos_kdl/html/classKDL_1_1Tree.html for more info. Should be pretty straight forward.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Smits](https://answers.ros.org/users/350/ruben-smits/) with karma: 543 on 2019-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1